# RecyclerView.Adapter отключить обновление элементов

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerviewadapter

Здравствуйте, у меня имеется RecyclerView с 10 эл. и когда листаешь до 10 и обратно он выгружает первые элементы и загружает обратно. (смена страниц производится кнопкой и мне не нужно их обновлять. 10 эл не так много, элементы берутся из List)

Как мне сделать так чтобы он загрузил все 10 эл. и не обновлял их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mRecyclerView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
mRecyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(10);
```

Comment: спасибо, не знаете со скольких эл. стоит оставить как есть, разве есть какая то существенная нагрузка ели данные  не подгружаются?

Comment: @Arntv, тут много нюансов. Если в ячейках у вас `WebView` с включённым `JavaScript` и вы в них грузите тяэелые сайты с многометровыми картинками, да ещё и `JS` грузит что-то, то лагать будет аццки и почти сразу `OOM` словите. Если в каждой ячейке у вас просто строчка текста то, думаю, проблем не будет и при нескольких сотнях закешированных элементов. Т.е. в каждом случае всё по разному. Чем проще элемент - тем больше можно закэшировать.

Comment: Это частное решение, на мой взгляд проблема кроется в самом ViewHolder'e.

Comment: @Morozov, ну да) Если ТС не обманывает и у него совсем мало ячеек и он их не обновляет, то можно и так оставить. Если обновляет - то можно наловить много багов. Сам я много раз пробовал использовать этот способ но каждый раз от него отказывался, т.к. ячейки после такого сложно заставить перерисовываться